# Windows 8 shell extension

Tags: windows-8, explorer, windows-shell

I'm trying to impelement C++ Windows Shell context menu handler on windows 8 - ARM,32 and x64.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a

With a some differences I managed to get the project working on XP and W7 (32,64).

The thing is, that registering the dll in W8 works withount any errors. But it doesn't work. Don't know why but I didn't find any usefull information that would describe differences between the OSes.

The same is with this project:
https://cfx.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Visual%20Studio%202008/ATLShellExtIconOverlayHandler/ReadMe.txt

No errors but it just doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.